# Expandable ListView Similar to Twitter

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I am looking for a custom expandable ListView similar to the one in the Twitter app.

I have looked at SlideExpandableListView located here: https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView  but it has to have a button reveal the menu, rather than onLongClick and it takes up more space in the list. I would prefer the menu to show over the ListView item.

I have searched the web but can't find anything similar to the Twitter implementation. Does anybody know of an implementation that could help?

Thanks,
Justin

Twitter Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just add a listener to the SlideExpandableListView? https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView/blob/master/library/src/com/tjerkw/slideexpandable/library/SlideExpandableListView.java

Comment: Ahh yes I didn't catch that. Thanks for the answer. That solves the onLongClick problem but not the space issue. Since that is the main problem, I will accept your answer. Thanks!